# Real Analysis: Riemann Sum

Tags: real-analysis

Use upper and lower Riemann sums for the partition $\{0,\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6},\pi\}$ of $[0,\pi]$ to prove that
$\frac{\pi}{3}<\int_0^{\pi} \sin(x)dx<\frac{5\pi}{6}.$

Attempt at an answer:
$\sum_{i=1}^n f(c_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$

$L(f,P)=f(\frac{\pi}{12})(\frac{\pi}{6})+f(\frac{\pi}{2})(\frac{2\pi}{3})\approx 2.23$

$U(f,P)=f(\frac{\pi}{2})(\frac{2\pi}{3})+f(\frac{11\pi}{12})(\frac{\pi}{6})\approx 2.23$

But, these cannot be the same because $\int_0^{\pi} \sin(x) =2$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you got the right lower and upper sums? Review the definitions.

Comment: you could also do darboux sums...would this be the correct way? I think I may have found where I went wrong:

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, you should review the definitions of lower and upper sums and Already an answer has been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your lower sum you have
$$
L(f,P)=\frac{\pi}{6}f(c_1)+\frac{2\pi}{3}f(c_2)+\frac{\pi}{6}f(c_3)
$$
where the $f(c_i)'s$ are the minimums that $f$ takes over each subinterval.  Notice that
$$
f(c_1)=0, f(c_2)=\frac{1}{2},f(c_3)=0
$$
because $f$ has minimums at $c_1=0$, $c_2=\frac{\pi}{6}$, and $c_3=\pi$.  So, the lower sum becomes
$$
\frac{2\pi}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{\pi}{3}.
$$
Now do the same for $U(f,P)$.

Comment: $U(f,P)=(\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}))(\frac{\pi}{6})+(\sin(\frac{5\pi}{6}))(\frac{2\pi}{3})+(\sin(\frac{5\pi}{6})(\frac{\pi}{6})=\frac{\pi}{2}$...Thanks! I haven't done these in awhile, all I needed was the extra push!

Comment: @Ashley For your second value, you should be using $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$ as that is the maximum between $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{6}$.